# Model-to-model transformations using Henshin

Tags: eclipse, uml, transformation, class-diagram, relational-model

I'm currently working on an end of cycle project named: " Mapping an uml class diagram into a relational database model using the model-to-model transformation tool Henshin".

I've successfully been able to transform classes, attributs and 1..1 associations, however i'm facing a problem regarding the 1..N and N..N associations. the 1..N and N..N associations have different rules of transformation, but since the N..N association is a 1..N association in both ways (1->N and N<-1), Henshin isn't able to differentiate between the two rules and is executing for the N..N associations the rule of 1..N association twice !!

I don't know how to fix this probelm. I'm not very familiar with Henshin since i'm just a beginner. Thank you for reading and i hope some of you can help !

Comment: I don't know Henshin, but it's very likely that it doesn't support the case of bidirectional many-to-many associations because this case is not supported by the Ecore modeling language. Ecore would need to support some kind of markup of which two reference properties are to be paired for forming the bidirectional association (like the 'mappedBy' annotation in JPA).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indeed, Henshin doesn't support bidirectional many-to-many associations.

Comment: what's the question? - if you know it does not work, nobody can fix it.